# How does a filtered table work in PrimeFaces?

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces, filter

I am trying to implement my own filtered table and I am struggling with understanding how it exactly works.

Redueced example from the PrimeFaces [showcase](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/datatable/filter.xhtml):

```
<h:form>
<p:dataTable var="car" value="#{dtFilterView.cars}" widgetVar="carsTable"
             emptyMessage="No cars found with given criteria" filteredValue="#{dtFilterView.filteredCars}">

    <p:column filterBy="#{car.price}" headerText="Price" footerText="custom (min)" filterFunction="#{dtFilterView.filterByPrice}">
        <h:outputText value="#{car.price}">
            <f:convertNumber currencySymbol="$" type="currency"/>
        </h:outputText>
    </p:column>
</p:dataTable>
```

My main problems with understanding how it works are:

1. The filter-function is called via EL without parameters, whereas the filter-function in the managed-bean needs `Object value, Object filter, Locale locale`
2. The data-table points to two collections. First the actual values without filtering and second an own collection for filtered values.

Code of the filter-function form the showcase:

```
public boolean filterByPrice(Object value, Object filter, Locale locale) {
    String filterText = (filter == null) ? null : filter.toString().trim();
    if(filterText == null||filterText.equals("")) {
        return true;
    }

    if(value == null) {
        return false;
    }

    return ((Comparable) value).compareTo(Integer.valueOf(filterText)) > 0;
}
```

**QUESTION 1:** How does the filter-function from the managed-bean gets the parameters it needs ?

**QUESTION 2:** Why does it need `Locale locale` ?

**QUESTION 3:** When and where does it write to the collection which contains the filtered values ?

Comment: It is normally good practice to ask 1 question per question per question.  Bt in this case the answer can be very easily found by yourself. Take a look at the PrimeFaces sourcecode. It is open and free for everyone. I doubt any one explicitly knows the answer in detail you'd like to have. Buttbe second question is even totally independent of PrimeFaces. Filetering is looking if one value matches another (pattern). That can be dependent on language (string compare), format (date etc) so the client Locale needs to be passed in to be able to do that.

Comment: you're right, i'll post the answer myself after researching